# Django login redirect_field_name 'next' forces new session

Tags: django, django-views, django-login

I'm building an e-commerce website, I enable guest users to add products to their carts saving the `cart_id` in session and when they proceed to checkout, I redirect them to login as follows inside the checkout view

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    login_url = reverse('accounts:login')
    check_out_url = reverse('cart:checkout')
    redirect_url = "{}?next={}".format(login_url, check_out_url)
    return redirect(redirect_url)
# checkout process here
```

It works, however the `cart_id` is no longer in the session.
If I don't use the next parameter and just redirect to `login_url` the `cart_id` stays in session.

P.S:
Same thing happens with `login_required_decorator`

Is there a way to keep the session data intact ?

Answer (score 0):

We'd need more info to know for sure, but here's a best guess based on experience:

Are you sure the redirect is taking you to the same domain, in cookie terms?

eg, if you're authenticated on `foo.somedomain.com` and the `next` references `www.somedomain.com`, then Django (by default) will want to use separate cookies for those two, separate domains.

To make Django use a cookie across all subdomains for a given domain, you'll want to set `settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain)) to just the domain. eg `somedomain.com`